# What's the translation of "proffer" in French?

Tags: traduction, droit-et-justice

From https://www.burnhamgorokhov.com/criminal-defense-resources/white-collar-crimes/understanding-proffers-in-federal-and-white-collar-criminal-cases/:

> The individual is under investigation or has been charged with a crime, and wants to offer information to law enforcement authorities in exchange for some benefit, such as dropped or reduced charges or an agreement for a lower sentence.

The proposal to give such information is referred to as a *proffer*. What's the translation of *proffer* in French? My guess would be "offre de preuve" but I wonder if there exists a more accurate legal term. Google Translate and DeepL didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

C'est un substantif, « (proposition d')[accord d'immunité conditionnelle](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=PROFFER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) » ; à [distinguer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proffer) du contexte du droit de la preuve où il s'agit de « présenter/offrir une preuve » ([*to tender/proffer evidence*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=PROFFER%20EVIDENCE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)).